# unable to print data by id

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Here is my query. I am trying to get `chat_from` id and fetch data behalf of this.
But this query returns all data.

if any idea please let me know.

```
$chatfrom = $this->input->post('chat_from');
$this->db->select('chat_id,chat_from,message,created_date',$chatfrom);
$userchatData = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix('usres_chat'))->result_array();
```

Comment: What about 'where' clause?

Comment: there in no where clause in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you:**

*Missing `where` clause in your query , and remove second parameter from `select`*

Should be like this

```
$chatfrom = $this->input->post('chat_from');
$this->db->select('chat_id,chat_from,message,created_date');

/*replace `chat_from` with your table column name if it is not */

$this->db->where('chat_from',$chatfrom);
$userchatData = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix('usres_chat'))->result_array();
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html